# Rails mails sent with Amazon SES wrong format in Mac mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, email, amazon-web-services

I have a Rails webapp deployed in an Amazon EC2 instances that is using email templates in html with a header and logo and SES Amazon email service to send notification emails.

The emails are sent and correctly and they are displayed perfectly in all mail clientes (i.e. gmail, hotmail) even my mobile phone but in the Mac mail, where the logo is not displayed correctly.

Please, see a screenshot attached.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I´m testing with Chrome and a Gmail account. If I open exactly same email in both (Mac mail and Chrome) I can see it right in Chrome, however, I see it wrong in Mail. I have checked the logo size is not been respected from CSS in Mail.

Please, see an screenshot from Gmail in Chrome. I see it right on mobiles too.
[image]

I attach the Rails code to generate the email:

**In email_service.rb:**

```
  # booking request admin
  def send_booking_request_admin_notification(customer, provider, boat, booking)
    @customer = customer
    @provider = provider
    @boat = boat
    @booking = booking
    attachments.inline['logo.png'] = File.open("#{Rails.root.to_s + '/app/assets/images/logo.png'}", "rb") {|io| io.read}   
    mail(from: APP_CONFIG['YANPY_EMAIL_FROM'], to: APP_CONFIG['YANPY_EMAIL_FROM'], subject: t('booking_request_Yanpy_subject', user_email: customer.email , owner_email: provider.email, booking_code: booking.code))
  end
```

**In send_booking_request_admin_notification.erb:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yanpy.dev/css/emails.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="nav-bar">
        <%= image_tag attachments['logo.png'].url, alt: 'Yanpy', size: '87x30', :class => "logo" %>
    </div>
    <div id="mail-content">
        <h4><%= t('admin_hello') %></h4>
        <p><%= t('booking_request_Yanpy_content_1', user_email: @customer.email, boat_name: @boat.name , owner_email: @provider.email, booking_code: @booking.code) %></p>
        <p><%= t('admin_goodbye_1') %></p>
        <p><%= t('admin_goodbye_2') %></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to reproduce the issue by resizing the browser Chrome windows in height and width but I couldn´t.

**UPDATE 2:**
I attach the relevent HTML code from Gmail in Chrome (working):

```
<div style="background:#f8f8f8;margin:0px;padding:0px" bgcolor="#f8f8f8">

    <div style="background:#1b1b1b linear-gradient(to bottom,#222,#111);border:#252525;min-height:50px;width:100%">
        <img alt="Yanpy" height="30" src="?ui=2&amp;ik=836c81b94f&amp;view=fimg&amp;th=149e8a5ae9582fb1&amp;attid=0.1&amp;disp=emb&amp;attbid=ANGjdJ8q_xSPAswkC2fDqsoAHPR0qKIUHUDjW45HorJli1u9zmcocdWFYXYi2rysx9cYcvsx7KJScrWLqDHBAOP-5W5g7LynDaj0cnMtQyS_P7D3A8ihhvpRKBLttmw&amp;sz=w174-h60&amp;ats=1416947426145&amp;rm=149e8a5ae9582fb1&amp;zw&amp;atsh=1" width="87" style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:10px" class="CToWUd">
</div>
```

Now, from Mac Mail not working (note: I´m not sure if this is the real code, I don´t know how to get it from Mail. I just forwarded the email to a Hotmail account and got it from there):

```
<div style="background-color:rgb(248, 248, 248);padding:0px;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;letter-spacing:normal;line-height:normal;text-align:start;text-indent:0px;text-transform:none;white-space:normal;word-spacing:0px;"><div style="background-color:rgb(27, 27, 27);border:rgb(37, 37, 37);height:50px;width:727px;background-position:initial initial;">

<img id="ecx52214002-0011-49E6-B577-6C08A8DA9C9E" height="121" width="352" src="https://dub126.afx.ms/att/GetInline.aspx?messageid=5293f1b7-74df-11e4-9417-00237de45652&amp;attindex=0&amp;cp=-1&amp;attdepth=0&amp;imgsrc=cid%3a32FDE1B1-DA1A-4A66-B63C-BBB067B5AB81%40Home&amp;cid=ed5bb1624ed90a36&amp;shared=1&amp;hm__login=roberto.chingon&amp;hm__domain=hotmail.com&amp;ip=10.148.132.8&amp;d=d3103&amp;mf=0&amp;hm__ts=Wed%2c%2026%20Nov%202014%2008%3a11%3a10%20GMT&amp;st=roberto.chingon&amp;hm__ha=01_745f8f086a98f87d549a0721ddd5738b4bfecce8795f549762672eea9f5cf5ba&amp;oneredir=1"></div><div style="padding:20px;"><h4>Hola Admin,</h4><p>El usuario prueba se ha registrado con el email<span class="ecxApple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span><a href="mailto:propietario.yanpy3@gmail.com">propietario.yanpy3@gmail.com</a><span class="ecxApple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span>correctamente.</p><p>Un saludo,</p><p>El equipo de Yanpy.</p></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Working with emails you have to develop like an old school HTML, I mean, you cannot link to external CSS files. Instead, you should add your css properties directly in the HTML template. Even better if it´s inline css in the style attribute of the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Mail uses WebKit rendering engine similar to Outlook for Mac, you should try to test it with WebKit browsers like Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Sorry, I don´t get your point. I use Chrome and Safari to open the Hotmail and Gmail webmails, and it´s displayed right. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yeah try to replicate the issue in WebKit browsers - maybe resize it to the display box of Apple Mail and see if it creates the issue. If not maybe create a github gist of your code so we can test it out.

Comment: The problem is in HTML/CSS not the RoR script/template. Update with that relevant reproducible example.